# Selecting a count into a variable in oracle

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, count

Hi I have been trying this today and haven't had any luck. this stored procedure does not work :(

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LEAD_PURGE(closed IN DATE,
oprtr IN INTEGER,
leadscount OUT INTEGER)

is
BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LEADS_DELETED INTO leadscount;

COMMIT;
END LEAD_PURGE;
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The INTO clause is misplaced.  It should be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO leadscount FROM LEADS_DELETED
```

Answer (score 11):

you have the `into` at the wrong place.

Try something like this instead and proceed from there:

```
declare
  cnt number;
begin
  select count(*) 
  into cnt
  from leads_delete;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way :

```
declare
  cnt number;
  cmd varchar2(100);
begin
  cmd := 'select count(*) from leads_delete';
  execute immediate cmd into cnt;
end;
```